# Python - Accessing a password protected website through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

I'm relatively new to programming but I'm beginning work on a project that will be used in my day job. My end goal is to create a program that automatically downloads PDF's from a website once a month and puts them in specific directories on my PC. This is uncharted territory for me and so I'm trying to think through the steps.

The first problem I need to overcome is the website is password protected.

So I need to access the site then automatically enter a username and password and login. I've read Selenium would probably be the module for this.

Can anybody advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Selenium is a good fit.

You can simulate button presses, key strokes, mouse swipes, so you can log in, navigate and download your files.

You can even make it run in the background if you make sure it does what it's supposed to do.

[This is a fun example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvFAuUcowT4)

Be careful though, the website may have a way of [detecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) it incorporated in it.

Comment: Thanks for that. We do have permission to be in the back end of the website, it's a supplier so it shouldn't be too much of an issue. I'll follow that tutorial, hopefully it applies to what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you!